# Vuex getter reactivity issue (in combination with Vue router)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a `Vuex` getter that is supposed to get all relevant data for the current route & then display it in `Vuetify` `<v-data-table>` which works completely fine when the component is created. However, when i create a new entry in the data `Array` in the relevant `state` that the `getter` works with, it only fetches & displays the new entry when i navigate away from the current route. I'm using the current route as a key to identify the different entries in the `state` so i can display different information for the current route, hence the `Vue router`.
I'm not sure if explained my issue clearly (sorry, English is not my first language), so here's code that i think is relevant:
The getter in question:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      geData: "geData"
    }),
    getAllData() {
      return this.geData[this.$route.path];
    }
  }
```

The data table:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="getAllData" hide-actions>
  <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.state}}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.created_at }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ }}</td>
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Here's how i modify the array in the store `mutation`:

```
  setNewData: (state, Data) => {
    state.Data[Data[0]] = Data[1];
  }
```

The first `Data[0]` is the route to be used as a key, the second `Data[1]` is the new data.
I suspect the reason the `getter` updates only when i navigate away from the current route is because i use the route as a key, but i'm not certain and i dont know if that's the case how to adress the issue, so any ideas, pointers are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you modifying the array? Sounds like it could be a reactivity issue. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: @skirtle Hello sir, i added a brief explanation how i'm modifying the array with some code, if it's not too much trouble can you look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `Vue.set` because object keys are not reactive unless first declared:

```
Vue.set(state.Data, Data[0], Data[1])
```

That should get you the reactivity you're looking for.

Side note:

Make sure that `state.Data` is reactive to begin with by initializing it as an object.

Comment: Sir, thank you very much! I did as you suggested (changed `state.Data` to an object) and then used `Vue.set(state.Data, Data[0], Data[1])` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
setNewData: (state, Data) => {
  Vue.set(state.Data, Data[0], Data[1])
}
```

You'll need to import `Vue` if you don't already have it in that file.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats.

I'm assuming here that you're adding a new property to the object. If the property already exists then you wouldn't need `Vue.set`.

An alternative would be to copy the object, adding the new property before the new object is made reactive:

```js
setNewData: (state, Data) => {
  state.Data = {
    ...state.Data,
    [Data[0]]: Data[1]
  }
}
```